# How to mark duplicate record as checked

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, aura, console

How to unchecked duplicate account record that have opportunity/contact or both. 
Default duplicate__c is false.

Example:

Suppose, there are total 3 duplicate name record, with one duplicate name record having either opportunity or contact or both and rest 2 duplicate name record don't have opportunity and contact then the result should marked two checkbox(duplicate__c) true. In my case it is returning 1 record as checked

Similarly for 4 duplicate name records , if one record is having opportunities or contact and the rest 3 don't have relationship with opportunity and contact.In my case it is marking 2 record true(checked). But it should be 3 record to be true(checked).

**I cannot build up logic help me to sole above cases.**

```
List<Account> actLst = new List<Account>();
Set<String> userNames = new Set<String>();

Map<Id,Account> accAll= new Map<Id,Account>();
    for(Account a:[Select Id, Name from Account])
        {accAll.put(a.Id,a);}

Map<Id,Account> accDup = new Map<Id,Account>();
    for(Account a:[SELECT Id,Name,duplicate__c FROM Account where Id Not In (Select AccountId from Contact) And 
                    Id Not In (Select Account_Name__c from Opportunity__c)])
        {accDup.put(a.Id,a);}

Map<Id,Account> accCont = new Map<Id,Account>();
     for(Account a:[SELECT Id,Name,duplicate__c FROM Account where Id In (Select AccountId from Contact)])
        {accCont.put(a.Id,a);}

Map<Id,Account> accOpp =new Map<Id,Account>();
     for(Account a:[SELECT Id,Name,duplicate__c FROM Account where Id In (Select Account_Name__c from Opportunity__c)])
        {accOpp.put(a.Id,a);}

for(Account account_i : accAll.values())
{    
if(!(accCont.containsKey(account_i.Id)) )  //|| (!accOpp.containsKey(account_i.Name))) 
   {   
     if((accDup.containsKey(account_i.Id)) )
        {
            if(!(userNames.contains(account_i.Name)) ) 
              {
                userNames.add(account_i.Name);
                system.debug('UserName');
                System.debug(account_i.Id);   
              }
            else
            {
               account_i.duplicate__c = true;
               actLst.add(account_i);
               System.debug('1');
               System.debug(account_i.Id); 
            }
        }
       else
         {
            System.debug('Relationship record ' +account_i.Id);       
         }
   }
    else
    {
       System.debug('2');
       System.debug(account_i.Id);  
    }

}
    system.debug('actLst >> ' + actLst);
update actLst;
```

Comment: according to console it is not reaching here else if(accCont.containsKey(account_i.Name)) i.e the condition(false) is not getting satisfied   if((!accCont.containsKey(account_i.Name)) )

Comment: Please don't post the same question repeatedly. Instead, edit your existing post to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

This `Map` constructor pattern:

```
Map<String,Account> accCont = new Map<String,Account>([
    SELECT Id,Name,duplicate__c
    FROM Account
    where Id In (Select AccountId from Contact)
]);
```

always takes the `Id` value from the query and uses it as the key. So while you can use `Map<String,Account>`, better to make it `Map<Id,Account>`. From the [Map Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm) documentation:

> Creates a new instance of the Map class and populates it with the
>   passed-in list of sObject records. The keys are populated with the
>   sObject IDs and the values are the sObjects.

So any other logic **must also be based on `Id` values** i.e.:

```
if((!accCont.containsKey(account_i.Id)) )
```

The idea behind having a unique identifier field as well as a name field is to ensure that each table row can be separately found. For example, multiple people could have the `Name` "Palash", but the record including your data will have a distinct `Id` value.

If you definitely want to do some logic based on the name, you have to use a loop to grab the data but the last row with a particular name will be the only one left in the map:

```
Map<String,Account> accCont = new Map<String,Account>();
for (Account a : [
        SELECT Id,Name,duplicate__c
        FROM Account
        where Id In (Select AccountId from Contact)
        ]) {
    accCont.put(a.Name, a);
}
```

Note that queries like this with no `where` limits on the number of rows returned will very likely run into [governor limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm). You need to think about that now not later as it will likely change the design.

The platform has a built-in [duplicate rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_rules_map_of_reference.htm) mechanism. Using that instead will save you a lot of pain. If the requirements you are working to don't match those capabilities, it is well worth re-negotiating the requirements.

Comment: we can directly put the soql query in assigning walue that is Map<String,Account> accCont = new Map<String,Account>([SELECT Id,Name,duplicate__c
        FROM Account
        where Id In (Select AccountId from Contact)])

Comment: @Palash I don't understand your point. Yes that code will execute, but the Map key will be the Id field value not the Name field value.

Comment: actually i want to compare name that's why i take name as key.

Comment: @Palash OK, to do that you will need to use the last piece of code I posted.

Comment: can you build up logic for the above cases

Comment: @Palash Sorry, no that is your job.